# Can't split hebrew word into an array PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays

i'm trying to get hebrew input via GET method and split it into an array, though the page is encoded, I stil get results like this: Array ( [0] => � [1] => � [2] => � [3] => � [4] => � [5] => � [6] => � [7] => � ) (The word is מילה)

Here is my code, what am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $word = $_GET['word'];
        $arr = str_split($word);
        print_r($arr);
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can You write a URL to this page where You're getting this `$_GET` variable?

Comment: Sure, i'm using WAMP: http://10.0.0.2/hebrewtest/test.php?word=מילה

Comment: Well, as You can see in the comment, Your `$_GET['word']` is a little bit strange :P. It should be in UTF8 encoding.

Comment: So what to do with my hebrew word :|

Comment: Store it somewhere in the code or database and create a key (in UTF-8) to it.

Comment: Sorry for the foolish comment but i'm pretty new and i'm not sure how to do it, can you send me a link about it or something? :)

Comment: `str_split` expects single-byte encodings. If your text is encoded with a multi-byte encoding, you need a multi-byte aware function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work for you.

```
<?php
 function mb_str_split( $string ) {
 # Split at all position not after the start: ^
 # and not before the end: $
 return preg_split('/(?<!^)(?!$)/u', $string );
 }

 $string   = 'מילה';
 $charlist = mb_str_split( $string );

 print_r( $charlist );
?>    


Another way,

function mbStrToArray ($string) {
$strlen = mb_strlen($string);
while ($strlen) {
    $array[] = mb_substr($string,0,1,"UTF-8");
    $string = mb_substr($string,1,$strlen,"UTF-8");
    $strlen = mb_strlen($string);
}
return $array;
}

 $result=mbStrToArray('מילה');
 print '<pre>';
 print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function splitMultiByte($string) {
  $output = array();
  for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {
    $output[] = mb_substr($string,$i,1,'UTF-8');
  }
  return $output;
}
```

Well I think what causes the problem here is, that hebrew letters are not supported in ASCII and you therefore need to work with PHP functions that are prefixed with mb. They'll work with so called multibyte (letters that are represented by more than one byte) values.

You can use the function above. It should give you an array as expected.

Comment: there's also `mb_split`

Comment: Do you know why there are two blank characters when entering a hebrew String every time?

Comment: Can you give me an example string and tell me where exactly the blank characters occur? I'll try to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have enough reputation to add comment, so an answer instead:

there is a problem using `strlen` with hebrew and I guess other multibyte characters.

```
strlen('מילה') //equals 8 when in reality its 4 letters
mb_strlen('מילה') //also equals 8
```

better use:

```
mb_strlen('מילה', "UTF-8") //equals 4 as it should
```

So taking Johannes Kling's answer with this into an account we get:

```
function splitMultiByte($string) {
    $output = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($string, "UTF-8") ; $i++) {
        $output[] = mb_substr($string,$i,1,'UTF-8');
    }
    return $output;
}
```

`mb_strlen` uses "internal character encoding" by default, so if its not UTF-8 the count will be wrong. So setting UTF-8 explicitly is safest option imho.